# SQL Insert two rows in other table based on If confition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 table which is DATA and MAIN. DATA table is the raw data extract from excel and MAIN table is the data after validation(few rules) have been made.

Rule:

1. If Amoun1<>'' and Amount2<>''.
   Insert 2 row in MAIN table. The first row will have the value for Amount and Percentage from Amount2 & Percentage2 with TaxRateType = Taxable.
   And the second row will have Amount and Percentage get from Amount1 & Percentage1 with TaxRateType = EXEMPT. The invoiceNo also will be add with '_1'
2. If Amount2<>'' and Amount1=''
   Insert 1 row with Amount and Percentage from Amount2 & Percentage2 with TaxRateType = Taxable.
3. Else
   Insert 1 row with Amount and Percentage get from Amount1 & Percentage1 with TaxRateType = EXEMPT

The example is as below table:

```
**DATA**
InvoiceNo | TotalAmount | Percentage1 | Amount1 | Percentage2 | Amount2 
abc123         100             5           45          20          55
abc124          60             5           60          20
abc125          50             5                       22          50

**MAIN**
InvoiceNo | Percentage | Amount | TaxRateType | ReferenceValue
abc123          20         55      TAXABLE            2
abc123_1         5         45       EXEMPT            1
abc124           5         60       EXEMPT            1
abc125          22         50      TAXABLE            2
```

I'm stuck in here for 4 hours searching for which method to use. Currently I have an idea to use if exists but still it's not correct and somehow I feel its not a good method.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID from [alcatel].[Main_Temp] where Amount0<>'' and Amount21<>'')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [alcatel].[Main] 
    ( [Country],[InvoiceNo],[Amount],[Percentage],[TaxRateType],[Reference Value])
SELECT 
    [Country],[InvoiceNo],[Amount2],[Percentage2],'TAXABLE' as [TaxRateType],2 as [Reference Value]
FROM [alcatel].[Data];

INSERT INTO [alcatel].[Main] 
    ( [Country],[InvoiceNo],[Amount],[Percentage],[TaxRateType],[Reference Value])
SELECT 
    [Country],[InvoiceNo]+'_1' as InvoiceNo,[Amount1],[Percentage1],'EXEMPT' as [TaxRateType],'1' as [Reference Value]
FROM [alcatel].[Data];
END
Followed with other condition.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to unpivot the data with some logic:

```
select invoiceno + v.suffix, v.percentage, v.amount,
       v.taxratetype, v.referencevalue
from data d cross apply
     (values (1, d.Percentage1, d.Amount1, 'EXEMPT', ''),
             (2, d.Percentage2, d.Amount2, 'TAXABLE', (case when d.amount1 is not null then '_1' else '' end))
     ) v(ReferenceValue, Percentage, Amount, TaxRateType, Suffix)
where amount is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a8f5c2ff9e7d07cf47f8b8509c73b4c) is a db<>fiddle.